# Accessing dynamically loaded content by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Let's imagine a situation.

I have a ASP website, where I am loading contet to a div

so I have

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<button onClick="javascript:test()">Bla</button>
```

and I am loading content to it by jQuery :

```
$("#placeholder").load("@Url.Action("Add","Products")");
```

and now I want to have javascript test function which will work like this:

1) Access to a content loaded in the placeholder div, and find a form (named "FORM" inside this div, loaded from Product Controller Add action) and fire validate event:

I tried: `$("#Form").valid()` but it is not working.

What should I do ?

Comment: check if selector is found  `alert( $("#Form").length)` if value is 1 you have problems not shown in code provided. If zero, check ID is correct and proper case

Comment: Id is correct, but it cannot find it.

Comment: `cannot find it` doesn't explain much

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues with what you did:

1. You said the form had the *name* `FORM`, but you used an `id` selector to try to find it (`$("#Form")`). Either give it an `id`, or use `$("form[name=Form]")` to find it. I'd also make sure you use the same capitalization in both places (you said the name was `FORM` but you used `#Form` in your selector).
2. You need to find it *after* it's been loaded. `load` offers you a callback for that (the second argument).

So putting those together:

```
// Either give it an `id` (here I've assumed `id="theForm"` in the markup):
$("#placeholder").load("@Url.Action("Add","Products")", function() {
    // This is the load callback, called when the load is complete
    $("#theForm").valid();
});

// Or use the selector `form[name=Form]` to find it:
$("#placeholder").load("@Url.Action("Add","Products")", function() {
    // This is the load callback, called when the load is complete
    $("form[name=Form]").valid(); // <== Assuming the name is "Form" not "FORM"
});
```

---

Side note: You don't need or want the `javascript:` part of this:

```
<button onClick="javascript:test()">Bla</button>
<!--             ^^^^^^^^^^^---- lose this   -->
```

It has zero effect. You only use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in places where a URL is expected, such as the `href` on an `a` element. The old-style `onXyz` DOM0 handlers always use the default script for the page as a whole, which is JavaScript (unless you're using some ancient Microsoft-proprietary meta tag). The reason using `javascript:` there isn't actually an *error* is that it ends up being a [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12).

Comment: of course it should be ID not name, but i don't want to fire this immediatelly after loading the content, I want to do this after clicking on the button (which is not in loaded content)

Comment: @Backslash: Whether it has an `id` or `name` has nothing to do with when or how you load it, just how you find it after you have. If you currently have your `load` call in a `click` handler, just modify it as per the above. Since we're not looking for the selector until *after* the content is loaded (which is why we're using a callback), it'll get found -- whether it's by the (new) `id` you assign it, or the old `form[name=FORM]` instead.

Comment: Probably you dont' uderstand what i want to achieve.:

1) I got a div where I load a content
2) I have a button, and When it is clicked I want to find a form which were loaded to a div and force .valid() js. I don't want to force .valid() immediatelly after loading content to div, i want to fire it after button click.

Comment: @Backslash: That makes it even easier: Just put the `$("form[name=Form]").valid();` in the button `click` handler. It sounds like the problem may have purely been that you were using the wrong selector (an `id` selector, my point #1 above). You might want to include some handling for when they click the button when the form isn't loaded (in which case the jQuery object returned by `$("form[name=Form]")` will have `.length === 0` [or another way to check is if its `[0]` property is truthy]).